# Vue increment value inconsistance using v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to *increment/decrement* counter. Always ok but my input shows different value then in `this.count`. For example where I increment value. Input shows '3' but `this.count === 2`.

```
Vue.component('product-item', {
data: function () {
    return {
        count: 1  <==want inc/dec this value
    }
},
methods: {
   add(by) {
        let res = parseInt(this.count) + parseInt(by);
        this.count = res;    <== here I do it
    }
}
template:
`<button type="button" class="countpicker-dec" @click="add(-1)" :disabled="count < 2">-</button>

<input type="number" class="countpicker-num" v-model.number="count"> <==there I wanna see this.count

<button type="button" class="countpicker-inc" @click="add(+1)">+</button>`
```

Comment: I've checkked your code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-wind-l8hn7?file=/src/App.vue
And all is ok. It's working fine.

Comment: it drives me crazy. On web page I get '3' after increment click.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine as demonstrated below :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add(by) {
      let res = parseInt(this.count) + parseInt(by);
      this.count = res;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <button type="button" class="countpicker-dec" @click="add(-1)" :disabled="count < 2">-</button>

  <input type="number" class="countpicker-num" v-model.number="count">

  <button type="button" class="countpicker-inc" @click="add(+1)">+</button>

  <div>{{count}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 add() {
   this.count += 1;
}
```

If just add to increment by 1 ..why pass by parameter just increases in method

Answer (score 1):

To show the meaning `this.count` use

```
<p>{{this.count}}</p>
```

Shows the value you entered

```
<input type="number" class="countpicker-num" v-model.number="count">
```